# Molecular script addon permanently stuck in simulating state

Tags: add-on

I stopped the molecular simulation and... it's not stopped.
It just says that there is time left and when I play the simulation it's in its "slow mode" state.
I have no clue how to fix it and the other post on the forum doesn't help.

NOTE:
I have tried restarting blender, and that didn't help.

This is my first post on this forum so if you need any more info, ask.

-Grimtin10

Comment: i have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

Add  "free bakes" to *Quick Favorites*  and "process simulation left..."
At view port just press <kbd>Q</kbd> and menage simulation from there.
Good luck

Comment: this helped me!

Answer (score -1):

I fixed by assigning a shortcut to the bake tab, then clicking the shortcut once its finished baking.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on how you did that perhaps with some images illustrating the procedure

Comment: this did not help me, because it never finished baking. but with the answer from Czujny it finished baking. After that step all buttons worked as usual.